# Request for [codingbat] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

It would good to have a [codingbat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codingbat) tag for questions that related to solving code puzzles coming from [codingbat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codingbat).  Can we have a tag for [codingbat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codingbat) as we have on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 9):

No, we do not need this tag.  We already have a general [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) tag that encompasses all challenge sites.  Unlike Stack Overflow, we don't need a specific tag for everything.  Just use this tag for anything coming from CodingBat or any other challenge site.

Comment: But I can see a lot of questions being asked related to coding it would be easier for one to Identify common questions using the tag even avoid Duplicacy.

Comment: @Anirudh: Another option is to make it a synonym of [programming-challenge].  Other than that, there's no need for such a tag to be standalone.

Comment: @Anirudh even if two people post questions about the same challenge problem, it's not really a duplicate because they have created two separate implementations and each is a unique review.